# How to add a .o file to an Android ndk build

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk, object-files

I have a .o file for a 3rd party library.  I do not have the .c files for it, nor can I get access to them.  Normally this isn't a problem, I would just add this to the list of files to link in.  But I can't find a way to link in a file without compiling it in the NDK without altering the build scripts.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer.  Pain in the neck, but it works.  I had to turn my .o file into a .a file via the program ar, then create a new static module in my Android.mk file to turn it into a library that android could link via LOCAL_STATIC_LIBS.

Comment: can you please share your Android.mk